# Insert sequential paths in tables to images uploaded to folder

Tags: php

I'm trying to allow a user to upload 2 images to a folder created when they register, and insert the subsequent paths to the two files when uploaded, into my table which has 'main' as the first image path, and 'one' as the next image path.

The uploader correctly uploads the two files into the folder, but do I do an INSERT to insert image one path into 'main', and image two path into 'one' ??

The code is below for the upload....

Any help with this is much appreciated!!

```
<?php
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$uploadDir = "images/test/$username/";


$uploadsNeeded = '2';
for($i = 0; $i < $uploadsNeeded; $i++){
$file_name = $_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['name'];
// strip file_name of slashes
$file_name = stripslashes($file_name);
$file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);
$copy = copy($_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['tmp_name'],$uploadDir . $file_name);
 // prompt if successfully copied
 if($copy){
 echo "$file_name | uploaded sucessfully!<br>";
 }else{
 echo "$file_name | could not be uploaded!<br>";
 }


$filePath = $uploadDir . $file_name;

$sql = "UPDATE images SET main = '$filePath' WHERE userid = '$_SESSION[userid]'";
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "UPDATE images SET one = '$filePath' WHERE userid = '$_SESSION[userid]'";
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());    
}   

?>
```

Comment: Check out http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload (example) You might need to bracket the name input `<input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />`

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for your help...I've tried using [] in the input but no joy..code for input is....
<head>
<title>Upload files</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="test3.php">
  <p>
  <?
$uploadsNeeded = '2';
  for($i=0; $i < $uploadsNeeded; $i++){
  ?>
    <input name="uploadFile<? echo $i;?>" type="file" id="uploadFile<? echo $i;?>" />
  </p>
  <? } ?>
  <p><input name="uploadsNeeded[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $uploadsNeeded;?>" />
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need to do.....

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$username = $_SESSION['user_name'];

$uploadDir = "images/test/$username/";

$filePath = array();

$uploadsNeeded = '2';

for($i = 0; $i < $uploadsNeeded; $i++){

$file_name = $_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['name'];

// strip file_name of slashes

$file_name = stripslashes($file_name);

$file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);

$copy = copy($_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['tmp_name'],$uploadDir . $file_name);

// prompt if successfully copied

if($copy){

echo "$file_name | uploaded sucessfully!
";

}
else{

echo "$file_name | could not be uploaded!
";

}

$filePath[] = $uploadDir . $file_name;

}

$sql = "UPDATE images SET main = '$filePath[0]' AND one = '$filePath[1]' WHERE userid = '$_SESSION[userid]'";

```
$result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @ Fred apologies for the code layout...I'm new to this site!!...and user1787781 thanks for your answer..however it's just inserting a zero in the 'main' table and nothing in the 'one' table...thanks for your answer though... it's appreciated